# How to define a new type based on some key of items of an array?

Tags: typescript, types

There is already a const, which is an array:

```
const fieldTypes = [
    { id: 1, name: 'text'},
    { id: 2, name: 'list'},
    // ...
    { id: 10, name: 'switch'}
]
```

I want to define a new type based on the const `fieldTypes`

```
type IdToNamesType = ???
```

The real definition of `IdToNamesType` should be similar with:

```
type IdToNamesType = {
   1: 'text',
   2: 'list',
   // ...
   10: 'switch'
}
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem to fix is to ensure that the `id` and `name` are inferred as number and string literal types not as `number` and `string`. To do this we can use this function :

```
function fields<TId extends number, TName extends string, T extends { id: TId, name: TName }[]>(...o:T):T {
  return o;
}
const fieldTypes = fields(
  { id: 1, name: 'text'},
  { id: 2, name: 'list'},
  { id: 10, name: 'switch'}
);
/*
typeof fieldTypes = [{
    id: 1;
    name: "text";
}, {
    id: 2;
    name: "list";
}, {
    id: 10;
    name: "switch";
}]

*/
```

Now we can use a mapped type to transform the tuple type into an object type:

```
type IdToNamesType = { 
  [P in typeof fieldTypes[number]['id']] : Extract<typeof fieldTypes[number], { id: P }>['name']
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I wouldn't have thought of doing it that way.

Comment: Thanks so much. Typescript is really powerful on types.

Comment: @Freewind you are welcomed,  keep the interesting questions coming :)